# Moving many lines in a single buffer using Emacs `occur`

Tags: occur

Let's say I want to move all the lines in a buffer that contain the string 'global' to the end of that buffer. If I use Emacs `occur` it produces an occur buffer with the lines I need, but also includes line numbers at the beginning of each line. If I then use `rectangle-mark-mode` I can cut these lines, switch back to the original buffer, move to the end and yank. I am then left with blank lines in the original buffer, which need to be removed. Is there an easier and cleaner way to move lines containing a string to the end (or beginning of a buffer)?

Comment: I would use `kill-matching-lines` instead of `occur`.

Comment: I knew there had to be an easier way! Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a keyboard macro that:
   1.1. Search for the keyword
   1.2. cut the line
   1.3. Mark the location in a register
   1.4. Go to the end of the buffer
   1.5. Paste the line
   1.6. Go to the location marked in a register
2. Run the keyboard macro many e.g. 1000 times: `C-u 1000 M-x call-last-kbd-macro`